# Java. Get system default printer

Tags: java, printing

It is possible to get default system printer using Java Print Service API?

I can get list of all printers using

```
PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null)
```

but how to get printer choosed as *default* in system? (In screen-shot below, the default printer is checked (HP Laser Jet)).

[image: choosed default printer]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`PrintServiceLookup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html)

```
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

Acc. to Javadocs:

> **lookupDefaultPrintService** Locates the default print service for this environment. This may return null. If multiple lookup services each specify a default, the chosen service is not precisely defined, but a platform native service, rather than an installed service, is usually returned as the default. If there is no clearly identifiable platform native default print service, the default is the first to be located in an implementation-dependent manner.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html#lookupDefaultPrintService%28%29)

```
PrintService service = 
    PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
if (service != null) {
    String printServiceName = service.getName();
    System.out.println("Print Service Name is " + printServiceName);
} else {
    System.out.println("No default print service found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 PrintService service = 
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```